# Quantum Fourier Transform in the Period Finding Problem

Tags: shors-algorithm, quantum-fourier-transform

I am trying to prove that when applying the inverse QFT to the following state:

[image]

we get the following result:

[image]

However, I get a wrong prefactor. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong? Here my calculations:

[image]

Here, the last equality comes by realizing that y is an integer and thus all terms of the second bracket give 1. The first bracket can be evaluated as follows:

[image]

Then we can plug in:

[image]

Obviously I should get 1/sqrt(r) not sqrt(r), but I don't find my mistake...

Comment: see https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12390/proof-of-qft-for-a-periodic-function

Comment: your issue is that in the initial wave function the sum should be to to $m-1$ not $rm - 1$. Then the rest of your proof is correct as you won't end up with the additional factor $r$.

Comment: ahhh sometimes you do not see the forest for the trees... Thanks a lot! Should I delete this post since it is such a stupid mistake?

Comment: it happens to all of us!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The summation in the initial wave function should be
$|\phi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\sum^{m-1}_0$